# Magento 1 get file size of upload

Tags: magento-1.9, php, file

I want to display the size of the file in MB's using the php filesize option.

But for some reason my code does not seem to work, it does not display the file size. The uploaded file is inside the Magento media catalog folder.

What am I missing?

CODE:

```
<?php $file = '/h/p/file.pdf';?>
<?php echo filesize("../media/catalog".$file);?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because of your file path is incorrect, you should try with,

```
Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS. 'catalog'.DS. $file;
```

Comment: Thanks but sadly that still does not work, that gets the following path, but still no filesize: `/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/media/catalog/h/p/file.pdf`

Comment: please first check with `file_exist()`

Comment: For some reason I get that the file does not exist. But the path is correct and the file also exists on that specific path. What am I missing?

Comment: It's permission issue :) try to give enough permission for directory and maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287837/phps-file-exists-will-not-work-for-me

Comment: Got it, but now it is dispaly as bytes. Like vaulue is `5667597`. How can I easily transform this into MB?

Comment: I think its very common very problem just check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510434/format-bytes-to-kilobytes-megabytes-gigabytes or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501427/php-filesize-mb-kb-conversion